# Is there some formal way to update the browser detection files for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, browser-detection, control-adapter

I have an ASP.Net site on which we're using control adapters. We have the adapters mapped to a "refID" of "Default."

These adapters are working fine on all browsers *except* Chrome and Safari.  For those browsers, they do not execute.  I've given up trying to figure out why -- I have a question here on SO that no one has been able to answer, and I've been researching it for days now.  It's just inexplicable.

I have tested the same code in my local environment, and it works just fine.  Additionally, no one else can replicate my problem on other servers.  It seems to be somehow confined to the machines at my client's site.  Could they be somehow out-of-date?

If this is the case, is there some way to "update" the .browser files?  I'm half-tempted to just copy the .browser files out of the Framework directory from my machine over to theirs, but I'm curious is there's something more formal than this?  Is there some other source of data that ASP.Net uses for browser detection other than these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem (my control adapters not working) turned out to have nothing to do with the browser detection configuration.

I never did find out if there was a formal way to update these files, but I did -- at one point -- just copy entire "Browsers" directory over, and while it didn't fix my problem, it didn't seem to hurt anything either.

If you modify any of the .browsers files in the Framework directory, you need to run this file to recompile the definitions:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\aspnet_regbrowsers.exe
```